# Handling (2 raise to n) -1 conditions

Tags: c#, logic

I have one logical question. I have collection of employee objects
There are 3 filter criteria conditions which have handle
For e.g. Employee name, Office name, salary.

Now these filter criteria should match like (Employee name AND/OR Office name AND/OR salary)

So here I have to write (2 raise n) -1  if conditions to handle this situation.

Is there any other way we can do this.
For (Employee name AND/OR Office name) condition I m doing following

```
if (criteria.EmpName != "" && criteria.OfficeName != "")
    {  
      if (emp.EmpName == criteria.EmpName && emp.OfficeName == criteria.OfficeName) 
        {
              bIsMatch = true;
         }
    }
    else
    {
          if (criteria.EmpName != "" && emp.EmpName == criteria.EmpName)
             bIsMatch = true;
          else if (criteria.OfficeName != "" && emp.OfficeName == criteria.OfficeName)
            bIsMatch = true;
    }
```

Now if have to handle saraly also i have write min 5 conditions.

Is thr other way to do it?

Comment: "2 raise n" can be written as 2^n

Comment: I seriously doubt you're programming in C#, Java, and C++ at the same time. Why are you lying?

Comment: I am working on c#. But this question is more logical than specific language.

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag it with any language tag, you should tag it as `language-agnostic`. However, I think your code is C# specific enough that it should only be tagged `C#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair up your filtering conditions and have a single statement that encodes all the parameters:

```
if( (criteria.EmpName.equals("") || criteria.EmpName.equals(emp.EmpName))
    && (criteria.OfficeName.equals("") || criteria.OfficeName.equals(emp.OfficeName))
    && (criteria.Salary.equals("") || criteria.Salary.equals(emp.Salary)))
```

In each of the AND-ed expressions checks first if the filter is empty, if it is that piece will result in `true`, if it's not, then the check is performed against the corresponding value in `emp` and is `true` only when that check is `true`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think this is best and perfect solution. This way, I don’t required to have add multiple if conditions. It is not easy to understand,  but you explained it very well.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do it, but since you didn't specify one specific language and since I don't feel qualified to judge your coding style, here's one that keeps the general form of your code, while demonstrating some better logic:

```
bool bIsMatch = true;
if (criteria.EmpName != "" && criteria.EmpName != emp.EmpName) {
    bIsMatch = false;
} else if (criteria.OfficeName != "" && criteria.OffIceName != emp.OfficeName) {
    bIsMatch = false;
} /* Repeat for as many conditions as there are */

if (bIsMatch) {
    /* None of the checks above failed */
}
```

Comment: This, I think, is the best way because it is the easiest to understand & maintain.

Comment: You could also short-circuit and return immediately when you find a false *if* you don't need to return `false` if none of the conditions are checked.

Comment: @devPro yes it does. Trace through it carefully and show me where it would go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Start out by assuming you have a match and Then apply each criterion one by one.

```
bIsMatch = true;

if (bIsMatch && criteria.EmpName    != "") bIsMatch = emp.EmpName    == criteria.EmpName;
if (bIsMatch && criteria.OfficeName != "") bIsMatch = emp.OfficeName == criteria.OfficeName;
// ...
```

Or, write a helper function that does the matching.

```
bool IsMatch(String criterion, String value)
{
    return criterion == "" || criterion == value;
}
```

Then you can do everything in one big if statement:

```
if (IsMatch(criteria.EmpName,    emp.EmpName)    &&
    IsMatch(criteria.OfficeName, emp.OfficeName) &&
    ...
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the criteria individually and maintain a count of matches. That way you need only `n` conditions:

```
int matches = 0;

if (criteria.EmpName != "" && emp.EmpName == criteria.EmpName)
  matches++;
// similar code for other criteria

if (matches >= 2) { // as many matches as required
  // succeeded
}
```

Comment: Similar to hobbs' answer, but what you're really getting after is that there were any non-matches, not how many.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? The idea scales well for more filters, except that the mapping itself is *convention* based (name - name).

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>
              {
                { criteria.EmpName, emp.EmpName },       
                { criteria.OfficeName, emp.OfficeName},
                { criteria.ThirdProp, emp.ThirdProp }
              };

bIsMatch = dict.All(kvp => string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key) || kvp.Key == kvp.Value);
```

I would question the overall design though; there's something that doesn't seem right about it. How would you deal with the `Salary` field that you mention? Surely, that's not a `string`? What's the sentinel-value being used in that case?

Comment: salary will be integer. User may search for employee name starting with Emp1, office name ABC, salary > 10000

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are clear enough about the business logic before writing the code. According to your code, I can see that you want to check if `emp` and `criteria` have the same `EmployeeName` and `OfficeName`, any of the properties is considered to be the same if it's `string.Empty`. The code will be quite clear after yourself is clear. Here we go:

```
public static bool EmptyOrEquals(this string one, string another)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(another) || one.Equals(another);
}
bIsMatch = emp.EmpName.EmptyOrEquals(criteria.EmpName) 
            && emp.OfficeName.EmptyOrEquals(criteria.OfficeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Test each question individually and use a bit set to encode the combinations of answers.

This results in cleaner code because you only test each criteria once, it's compact yet readable, and yet you can easily plug in code to handle each combination.  And it's the fast too.  O(n) to test all the criteria and O(1) to find the actual combination.

For a small, fixed number of criteria, you can push bits around manually.  For many criteria, or for a solution that scales, use java.util.BitSet

Bit pushing example:

```
int bits = 0;

if (...criteria 1...) {
    bits = 1;
}

if (...criteria 2...) {
    bits |= 2;
}

if (...bits 3...) {
    bits |= 4;
}

switch (bits) {
case 0: // no criteria matched
    ;
case 1: // criteria 1 matched
    ;
case 2: // criteria 2 matched
    ;
case 3: // criteria 1 AND 2 matched
    ;
case 4: // criteria 3 matched
    ;
case 5: // criteria 1 AND 3 matched
    ;
case 6: // criteria 2 AND 3 matched
    ;
case 7: // criteria 1 AND 2 AND 3 matched
    ;
}
```

You can generalize this solution using java.util.BitSet to manipulate bits for n criteria (useful when n > 64!).  To facilitate quick look up, store the hash of each BitSet combination in a map that maps the hash code to a command class.